# How change host for mongodb using spring boot?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, host

Here are my beans:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<!-- Activate annotation configured components -->
<context:annotation-config/>

<!-- Scan components for annotations within the configured package -->
<context:component-scan base-package="document">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration"/>
</context:component-scan>

<!-- Define the MongoTemplate which handles connectivity with MongoDB -->

<mongo:mongo host="192.168.0.10" port="27017" />
<mongo:db-factory dbname="yourdb" />

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

Here is my DAO

```
@Repository
public class DocumentRepository {

    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    def insertDocument(DocumentModel document) {
        return mongoTemplate.insert(document)
    }
}
```

Every time I call insert I get the following error:

```
*Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting for a server that matches
 AnyServerSelector{}. Client view of cluster state is {type=Unknown, 
 servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=Unknown, state=Connecting,  
 exception={com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the 
 socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}]; 

 nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 
 10000 ms while waiting for a server that matches AnyServerSelector{}.

 Client view of cluster state is {type=Unknown, servers=
 [{address=localhost:27017, type=Unknown, state=Connecting, exception=
{com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the socket}, 
 caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}]*
```

Here is my main file

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("document , filter")
class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

I have mongodb running on a different box i.e. 192.168.0.10. For some reason it keeps showing it's trying to connect to localhost. Any ideas what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up getting the host to change by adding the following line to my main class.

```
/*
 * Factory bean that creates the com.mongodb.Mongo instance
 */
public @Bean MongoClientFactoryBean mongo() {
    MongoClientFactoryBean mongo = new MongoClientFactoryBean();
    mongo.setHost(host);
    return mongo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<mongo:mongo host="192.168.0.10" port="27017" />
<mongo:db-factory dbname="yourdb" />
```

with

```
<mongo:db-factory host="192.168.0.10" port="27017" dbname="yourdb" />
```

Answer (score 0):

When using

```
<mongo:db-factory dbname="yourdb" />
```

an internal Mongo client instance is registered with the db factory using the default host and port number.

In order to fix it, use

```
<mongo:db-factory dbname="yourdb" mongo-ref="mongo"/>
```

which references the mongo bean instance created just above.

Comment: This still didn't work. I added my main file as well just to see if I was missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using all those XML config stuff in addition to spring boot which does pretty much the same under the hood for you.
Add

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=192.168.0.10 
spring.data.mongodb.database=YOURDB
```

to your application.properties alternatively:

```
-Dspring.data.mongodb.host=192.168.0.10 -Dspring.data.mongodb.database=YOURDB
```

as parameters for your program

Comment: What context XML configuration to use, to make sure that this config is being used ?